# JavaFX progress bar causes severe window lag after a resize

Tags: java, windows, javafx, progress-bar

**Problem**

I have a decent sized javaFX window that appears to work perfectly well, until i resize any window in the application. After the resize all components that have a drop-down or similar action (ie. `Menu`, `ComboBox`, `TabPane`) become horribly slow.

**Cause**

I have narrowed the problem down to a progress bar, if i remove the progress bar from the scene i can resize the window(s) as much as i want, if i add it then any window resize and they start to become unresponsive for about half a second; sometimes as much as two seconds if i do a lot of resizing.

**The window**

A view of the window so that you can see all the components.

[image: The window with the progress bar]

I can't add all the window code as its simply way too much to post.

**Class with the progress bar**

```
/**
 * The class that holds and displays the progress bar
 */
public class BottomToolBarImpl extends ToolBar {

    /**
     * The label that display the "Waiting for input" text at the bottom of the
     * window
     *
     * The {@code LLabel()} class is a label that gets its text from a
     * properties file
     */
    private final Label text = new LLabel().setTextKey("waiting").register();

    /**
     * This is the progress bar itself that is causing the problem
     */
    private final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();

    /**
     * Constructs the tool bar and adds the components
     */
    public BottomToolBarImpl() {
        super();
        addItems();
    }

    /**
     * Adds the progress bar and label the this object
     */
    private void addItems() {
        Region r = new Region();
        r.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(r, Priority.ALWAYS);

        progressBar.setMinWidth(192);//This line has no effect on the performance

        this.getItems().add(r);
        this.getItems().add(text);
        this.getItems().add(progressBar);//If i comment out this line then all works perfectly
    }
}
```

**Additional information**

- Most of the visible components on the window (ie. `TableView`, `ToolBar`, `ListView`) are implementations. I doubt this is the problem
- A lot of the widely used components such as `Buttons` and `Labels` are implementations that implement an interface that allows them to use a key that then gets the key value from a language file for its text. This doesn't do much on the rendering side nor is it called very often so i also doubt this is the problem.
- The window starts up rather fast (less than a second).
- I have a gaming pc so my hardware should not be a problem.
- Java version: 1.8.0_40 (build 1.8.0_40-b25) 64-Bit

I suppose what i'm asking here is has any body else has this problem and if so how did you fix it?

Do you know what the problem could be? I don't think this is a bug as google doesn't have any/many results on it.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm completely stuck here.

**An mcve that reproduces the results**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Reproduce problem");

        final StackPane root = new StackPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));

        final VBox layout = new VBox(10);

        layout.getChildren().addAll(new MenuImpl(), new ProgressToolBar());

        root.getChildren().add(layout);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private class ProgressToolBar extends ToolBar {

        private final Label text = new Label("Random Text Here");

        private final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();

        public ProgressToolBar() {
            super();
            addItems();
        }

        private void addItems() {
            Region r = new Region();
            r.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            HBox.setHgrow(r, Priority.ALWAYS);

            progressBar.setMinWidth(192);

            this.getItems().add(r);
            this.getItems().add(text);
            this.getItems().add(progressBar); //Still causes the problem
        }
    }

    private class MenuImpl extends MenuBar {

        public final Menu FILE = new Menu("File", null, new MenuItem("A"), new MenuItem("B"), new MenuItem("C"));

        public MenuImpl() {
            super();
            this.getMenus().addAll(FILE);
        }
    }
}
```

Click on the 'File' Menu and scroll through the items before and after resizing the window.

Comment: There are two things that are unclear to me: 1) your `addItems()` method creates a `Region` but never uses it. 2) What happens in the method `getItems()` and `add(Node)` on that result. Please add that code to the question.

Comment: You may wish to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this (you will be more likely to get help if you succeed in creating one).

Comment: @hotzst The region is added. `this.getItems().add(r);` adds the region to list of components in the tool bar. The `getItems()` method is part of the `ToolBar`, its an `ObservableList` on the components to display in the tool bar.

Comment: @jewelsea I added the mcve that reproduces the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to this bug:

[[Windows] Very poor performance of application (or Menus) when using an Animation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088984).

As a workaround, run the program with `-Dprism.vsync=false` or `-Dprism.order=sw` as VM argument.

Comment: The `-Dprism.vsync=false` argument worked like a charm. Thanks.